# Population dynamics calculation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

I am trying to solve the question:

> > A population of protozoa develops with a constant relative growth rate of 0.7944 per member per day. On day zero, the population consists of two members. Find the population size after six days.

I used 2 different methods to solve the problem, and each method gave a different answer.

First method:

$\frac{dP}{dt}=0.7944P\\
\Rightarrow P_t=Ce^{0.7944t}\\
P_0=2=C\\
P_6=2e^{0.7944\times6}\approx 235$

$\text{}$

Second method:

$A=P(1+r)^n\\
A=2(1.7944)^6\approx 67$

$\text{}$

Which method is correct?

Comment: It's not an instantaneous growth, but a growth **per day**, hence the second method is right

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut The solution is here: (http://math.berkeley.edu/~zworski/1B/hw9495.pdf). According to this solution you are wrong, first method is true.

Comment: @i.ozturk Similar to the ambiguity between "[compound interest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Compound_Interest)" and "[continuously compounding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_interest#Continuous_compounding)", but daily here.  The US education system and finance industry has never managed to treat either clearly.

Comment: Noting Henry's comment, I now realise that the correct solution is the first method. The protozoa are continuously compounding their numbers (the question mentions 'relative growth rate').

Comment: @Henry I'm not in the US and for me the obvious would be the second method. However, I think I understand why the first is more correct. But I find the statement of the question ambiguous (or maybe my english is too poor)

Comment: @Jean-Claude Arbaut: I think that constant refers to a growth rate that does not change, for example, based on the size of the population (a Malthusian population model). As soon as the time passes t=0, the population is greater than 2 and so the population in the second instant will grow by 2 _plus_ the amount that the population grew by in the first instant. The antonym of _relative_ is _absolute_ - the absolute growth rate for 1 member over 1 day is $e^{0.7944}\approx 2.213$ but at each instant every member grows at a relative growth rate of 0.7944 per day.

Comment: @Jean-Claude My English is not poor.  I would agree with you that the question and answer are ambiguous or confusing, but this is typical of the US approach to compounding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally confirmed that the solution is 235. So your first method is true. According to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_growth_rate) and [this](http://aob.oxfordjournals.org/content/90/1/37) relative growth rate (RGR) is also calculated with the following formula:

$$RGR=(\ln{P_1}-\ln{P_0})/(t_1-t_0)$$

where $t_1$ and $t_0$ are time **in days** and $P_1$ and $P_2$ are population. If you put:

$$0.7944=\frac{\ln{}P-ln2}{6}$$

You find:

$$P\approx235$$